# Woman discovers she's the last known fae and has to go to a magical academy

Tags: story-identification

I read/listened to a book (part of a series) about a woman who discovered she’s the last known fae and has to attend a magical academy as an unknown.

She winds up “inheriting” a bunch of properties and there are fae dogs.

Answer (score 8):

This is *[**Upended Life**](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/48908446-upended-life)* by Erin R. Flynn.

This book series has the last fairy going to a magical university. There's also mention of fae dogs in a later book.

> My name is Tamsin Vale and my life is about to get real… Really
> complicated and ridiculously dangerous. Which is almost funny given at
> nineteen I already know too much of the darkness of the world and
> people, the secrets they keep.
>
> Or so I thought.
>
> Turns out those quirky abilities I’ve been keeping secret expose me to
> a world I didn’t know existed. Sure, I knew I wasn’t human—but how
> exactly do I find out more without ending up in the wrong hands?
>
> And I’m not so sure I’m in the right hands now given some of the
> reactions to finding me. They say I’m the last fairy. I’m not sure I
> should trust them when their thoughts are mostly of power and how to
> use me.
>
> But I’m also not sure I have much of a choice. My powers are dangerous
> and I don’t know how to use them. They promise to teach me what I need
> to know and give me a chance at something I’ve never had before.
>
> A normal life. I don’t think anything about Artemis University and
> those who attend is normal, but it’s still better than the life I’ve
> been living if they keep half their promises.
>
> [image: Cover of "Artemis University #1: Upended Life" by Erin R. Flynn. A red-haired woman in a black dress, high heels, and sunglasses stands in front of a building with a line of columns, with a blue semi-transparent circle immediately behind her.]

Comment: That’s it! I could not for the life of me remember anyone’s names.

Comment: @Kristen - Don't forget to upvote and click the 'accept' button (to the left of the answer) to show that it's correct.

Comment: @Kristen It's not really my thing, so I wasn't really paying attention, but I'm pretty sure at least one of this series came up on my e-book sale feeds this week, so you might want to check around.